# Service worker file can't find imported files

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, service-worker

For this service worker I am working on I have managed to get it working but am now looking to expand upon it. The idea would be for there to be separate mock data used dependant on whether it is the UK or US version of the website.

This is how it worked originally,

TestMode.ts:

```
class TestMode {
    constructor() {
        if (!this.isEnabled()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!('serviceWorker' in navigator)) {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            console.log('Browser does not support service workers');
            return;
        }

        this.init();
    }

    private init(): void {
        navigator.serviceWorker
            .register('worker.min.js')
            .then(this.handleRegistration)
            .catch((error) => {
                throw new Error('Service Worker registration failed: ' + error.message);
            });
    }

    private handleRegistration(registration: ServiceWorkerRegistration): void {
        registration.update();

        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('Registration successful, scope is:', registration.scope);

    }

    private isEnabled(): boolean {
        return locationService.hasParam('testMode');
    }
}

export default new TestMode();
```

serviceWorker.ts:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line spaced-comment
/// <reference lib="WebWorker" />

// export empty type because of tsc --isolatedModules flag

export type {};
declare const self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope;

const CACHE_NAME = 'mockData-cache';


const MOCK_DATA_RECORD: Record<string, string> = {
    '/units/all?availability=Active&roomTypeHandle=kitchens': 'mock-data/unitData.json',
    '/frontal-ranges/kitchens?': 'mock-data/kitchensData.json',
    '/carcase-ranges/?availability=Active&roomTypeHandle=kitchens': 'mock-data/carcaseRangesData.json',
    '/products/830368/related?roomTypeHandle=kitchens&productStateHandle=Active&limit=1000&campaignPhaseId=183&retailStore=Finishing%20Touches%20%28Extra%29': 'mock-data/relatedItems.json',
    '/carcase-placeholders?productStateHandle=Active&carcaseRangeHandle=Feature%20Bianco%20Grain&limit=1000&roomTypeId=1': 'mock-data/carcasePlaceholdersBiancoData.json',
    '/frontal-placeholders?productStateHandle=Active&frontalRangeHandle=Infinity%20Plus%20Milano-Ultra%20Bianco%20Gloss&limit=1000&roomTypeId=1': 'mock-data/frontalPlaceholdersActive.json',
    '/frontal-placeholders?productStateHandle%5B0%5D=Active&productStateHandle%5B1%5D=SemiRetired&frontalRangeHandle=Infinity%20Plus%20Milano-Ultra%20Bianco%20Gloss&limit=1000&roomTypeId=1':
        'mock-data/frontalPlaceholdersSemiRetired.json',
    '/carcase-placeholders?productStateHandle=Active&carcaseRangeHandle=Infinity%20Plus%20Milano%20White%20Edged&limit=1000&roomTypeId=1': 'mock-data/carcasePlaceholdersActive.json',
    '/api/json/unit-range-definitions?frontalRangeHandle=Infinity%20Plus%20Milano-Ultra%20Bianco%20Gloss&carcaseRangeHandle=Infinity%20Plus%20Milano%20White%20Edged&drawerBoxRangeHandle=Infinity%20Plus%20Glass%20Drawer%20Box&unitTypes=Base&orderPromotionId=183&roomTypeHandle=kitchens':
        'mock-data/unitRangeBase.json',
    '/api/json/unit-range-definitions?frontalRangeHandle=Infinity%20Plus%20Milano-Ultra%20Bianco%20Gloss&carcaseRangeHandle=Infinity%20Plus%20Milano%20White%20Edged&drawerBoxRangeHandle=Infinity%20Plus%20Glass%20Drawer%20Box&unitTypes=Wall&orderPromotionId=183&roomTypeHandle=kitchens':
        'mock-data/unitRangeWall.json',
    '/api/json/unit-range-definitions?frontalRangeHandle=Infinity%20Plus%20Milano-Ultra%20Bianco%20Gloss&carcaseRangeHandle=Infinity%20Plus%20Milano%20White%20Edged&drawerBoxRangeHandle=Infinity%20Plus%20Glass%20Drawer%20Box&unitTypes=Tower&orderPromotionId=183&roomTypeHandle=kitchens':
        'mock-data/unitRangeTower.json',
    '/api/json/unit-range-definitions?frontalRangeHandle=Infinity%20Plus%20Milano-Ultra%20Bianco%20Gloss&carcaseRangeHandle=Infinity%20Plus%20Milano%20White%20Edged&drawerBoxRangeHandle=Infinity%20Plus%20Glass%20Drawer%20Box&unitTypes=Island&orderPromotionId=183&roomTypeHandle=kitchens':
        'mock-data/unitRangeIsland.json',
    '/api/json/feature-unit-range-definitions?frontalRangeHandle=Infinity%20Plus%20Milano-Ultra%20Bianco%20Gloss&carcaseRangeHandle=Infinity%20Plus%20Milano%20White%20Edged&drawerBoxRangeHandle=Infinity%20Plus%20Glass%20Drawer%20Box&unitTypes=Base&orderPromotionId=183&roomTypeHandle=kitchens':
        'mock-data/featureUnitRangeBase.json',
    '/api/json/feature-unit-range-definitions?frontalRangeHandle=Infinity%20Plus%20Milano-Ultra%20Bianco%20Gloss&carcaseRangeHandle=Infinity%20Plus%20Milano%20White%20Edged&drawerBoxRangeHandle=Infinity%20Plus%20Glass%20Drawer%20Box&unitTypes=Wall&orderPromotionId=183&roomTypeHandle=kitchens':
        'mock-data/featureUnitRangeWall.json',
    '/api/json/feature-unit-range-definitions?frontalRangeHandle=Infinity%20Plus%20Milano-Ultra%20Bianco%20Gloss&carcaseRangeHandle=Infinity%20Plus%20Milano%20White%20Edged&drawerBoxRangeHandle=Infinity%20Plus%20Glass%20Drawer%20Box&unitTypes=Island&orderPromotionId=183&roomTypeHandle=kitchens':
        'mock-data/featureUnitRangeIsland.json',
    '/products?roomTypeHandle=kitchens&productStateHandle=Active&limit=1&campaignPhaseId=183&retailCategory.handle=Worktops&attributes.Worktop%20Type=Worktop%2CBreakfast%20Bar&selectedCollection=Infinity%20Plus%20Milano&retailSubCategory.handle=Timber&productMaterial.name=Timber':
        'mock-data/productsWorktopsTimber.json',
    '/products?roomTypeHandle=kitchens&productStateHandle=Active&limit=1&campaignPhaseId=183&retailCategory.handle=Worktops&attributes.Worktop%20Type=Worktop%2CBreakfast%20Bar&selectedCollection=Infinity%20Plus%20Milano&retailSubCategory.handle=Bespoke&productMaterial.name=Luxury%20Laminate':
        'mock-data/productsWorktopsLuxuryLaminate.json',
    '/products?roomTypeHandle=kitchens&productStateHandle=Active&limit=1&campaignPhaseId=183&retailCategory.handle=Worktops&attributes.Worktop%20Type=Worktop%2CBreakfast%20Bar&selectedCollection=Infinity%20Plus%20Milano&retailSubCategory.handle=Laminate&productMaterial.name=Laminate':
        'mock-data/productsWorktopsLaminate.json',
    '/products?roomTypeHandle=kitchens&productStateHandle=Active&limit=1&campaignPhaseId=183&retailCategory.handle=Worktops&attributes.Worktop%20Type=Worktop%2CBreakfast%20Bar&selectedCollection=Infinity%20Plus%20Milano&retailSubCategory.handle=K-Life&productMaterial.name=K-Life':
        'mock-data/productsWorktopsKLife.json',
    '/products?roomTypeHandle=kitchens&productStateHandle=Active&limit=1&campaignPhaseId=183&retailCategory.handle=Worktops&attributes.Worktop%20Type=Worktop%2CBreakfast%20Bar&selectedCollection=Infinity%20Plus%20Milano&retailSubCategory.handle=Bespoke&productMaterial.name=Luxury%20Bespoke':
        'mock-data/productsWorktopsLuxuryBespoke.json',
    '/products?roomTypeHandle=kitchens&productStateHandle=Active&limit=1&campaignPhaseId=183&retailCategory.handle=Worktops&attributes.Worktop%20Type=Worktop%2CBreakfast%20Bar&selectedCollection=Infinity%20Plus%20Milano&retailSubCategory.handle=Bespoke&productMaterial.name=Rhino%20Edge':
        'mock-data/productsWorktopsRhinoEdge.json',
    '/products?roomTypeHandle=kitchens&productStateHandle=Active&limit=1000&campaignPhaseId=183&productId%5B0%5D=1003558&productId%5B1%5D=1003544': 'mock-data/productsProductID1003544.json',
    '/products?roomTypeHandle=kitchens&productStateHandle%5B0%5D=Active&productStateHandle%5B1%5D=Inactive&productStateHandle%5B2%5D=EndOfLife&productStateHandle%5B3%5D=Dead&limit=1000&campaignPhaseId=183&retailSubCategory.handle%5B0%5D=MilanoProfiles&retailSubCategory.handle%5B1%5D=BaseTopProfile':
        'mock-data/productsBaseTopProfile.json',
    '/products?roomTypeHandle=kitchens&productStateHandle=Active&limit=1&campaignPhaseId=183&retailCategory.handle=Worktops&attributes.Worktop%20Type=Worktop%2CBreakfast%20Bar&productMaterial.name=Luxury%20Laminate&selectedCollection=Infinity%20Plus%20Milano&groupBy=plannerColour.name':
        'mock-data/productsWorktopsLuxuryLaminatePlannerColour.json',
    '/products?roomTypeHandle=kitchens&productStateHandle=Active&limit=1&campaignPhaseId=183&retailCategory.handle=Worktops&productMaterial.name=Luxury%20Laminate&plannerColour.name=Aleve&groupBy=edgeColour.name&selectedCollection=Infinity%20Plus%20Milano':
        'mock-data/productsWorktopsLuxuryLaminatePlannerColourAleve.json',
    '/products?roomTypeHandle=kitchens&productStateHandle=Active&limit=1000&campaignPhaseId=183&retailCategory.handle=Lighting': 'mock-data/productsLighting.json',
    '/products?roomTypeHandle=kitchens&productStateHandle=Active&limit=1000&campaignPhaseId=183&productId%5B0%5D=830368': 'mock-data/productsActiveProductID830368.json',
    '/products?productId=830368&campaignPhaseId=183&roomTypeHandle=kitchens': 'mock-data/productsProductID830368.json',
    '/products?roomTypeHandle=kitchens&productStateHandle=Active&limit=1000&campaignPhaseId=183&retailCategory.handle=MilanoProfiles&productColour.name=Camel':
        'mock-data/productsCamel.json',
    '/products/830368/related?roomTypeHandle=kitchens&productStateHandle=Active&limit=1000&campaignPhaseId=183&selectedCollection=Infinity%20Plus%20Milano&retailStore=Finishing%20Touches%20%28Extra%29':
        'mock-data/relatedItemsInfinityPlusMilano.json',
    '/products?roomTypeHandle=kitchens&productStateHandle%5B0%5D=Active&productStateHandle%5B1%5D=SemiRetired&limit=1000&campaignPhaseId=183&productId%5B0%5D=830368':
        'mock-data/productsSemiRetiredData.json',

};


self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
            .then(cache => {
                return cache.addAll(Object.values(MOCK_DATA_RECORD));
            }),
    );
    self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function () {
    return self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    const url = new URL(event.request.url);
    const pathAndQuery = url.pathname + url.search;

    if (pathAndQuery in MOCK_DATA_RECORD) {
        const cacheKey = MOCK_DATA_RECORD[pathAndQuery];

        event.respondWith(
            caches.match(cacheKey, {
                cacheName: CACHE_NAME,
            }) as Promise<Response>,
        );
    }
});
```

Now for expanding on this I have moved the mock data into another folder called mockServiceWorker, there is another one of these in the US folder as well. The idea of this to import both the GB and US versions of the mock data and then from a check, the service worker will determine which data it should use.

At the moment i am just trying to import the gb data and doing it like so:

```
import { MOCK_DATA } from './mockServiceWorker/mockData';
```

and now just trying to see it works by doing:

```
console.log(MOCK_DATA);
```

but whilst there are no errors in the workspace, in the terminal I am getting:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './mockServiceWorker/mockData' in '/Users/lewis.ross/git/planner2d/core'
```

Webpack is also used for this service worker. When the site is setup a worker.min.js file is generated in the dist folder and within there I am also getting the message:

```
function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module './mockServiceWorker/mockData
```

I am at a loss as to why it cannot find the file. Has anyone else experienced this and managed to fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has the same issue as me. Check how your webpack config is setup, I had added a separate part to the config for the service worker and forgot ad:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.json', '.hbs'],
    modules: [
        COUNTRY_CODE_PATH,
    ],
    alias: ALIAS_MAIN,
},
```

After adding this, I stopped getting the module not found errors.